# Matching exact array elements with indexOf (regex - boundary match arrays)

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, loops, indexof

I've come across a problem with matching arrays and strings, but the normal regex approach (boundary matching) doesn't seem to work in my case.

Do I need to use different word boundaries or does anyone have a cleaner solution?

```js
var nameArray = ['AA', 'BB', 'WBB'];
var idArray = ['AA','BB','CC'];

var counter=0;

for(var j=0; j<idArray.length;j++)
{
  for(var i=0; i<nameArray.length;i++)
  {
    if(nameArray[i].indexOf(idArray[j]) != -1) 
      counter++;
    
    /*
    if(nameArray[i].indexOf('/\b'+idArray[j]+'\b/') != -1) 
      counter++;
    */
    
    /*
    if('/\b'+nameArray[i]+'\b/'.indexOf(idArray[j]) != -1) 
      counter++;
    */   
      
  }
}

console.log(counter);
```

As you can see 3 matches are detected, but I need it to only recognize whole word matches (so 2 in this case).

The loops and structure are necassary since I need to process large arrays  in my project.

JSFiddle: [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/mw8xyhet/2/)

Comment: why don't you just check the whole content of the array-item using `nameArray[j] == idArray[i]`?

Comment: you are using `j` for `idArray`, and `i` for `nameArray` and then doing `nameArray[j]` and `idArray[i]` 

Comment: if `nameArray[j] == idArray[i]` works then its fine otherwise update the question with more examples

Comment: @KoushikChatterjee didn't noticed, mixed them up in the testscript, now edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Change **indexOf to ==**

```js
var nameArray = ['AA', 'BB', 'WBB'];
var idArray = ['AA', 'BB', 'CC'];

var counter = 0;

for (var j = 0; j < idArray.length; j++) {
  for (var i = 0; i < nameArray.length; i++) {
    if (nameArray[j] == idArray[i])
      counter++;

  }
}

console.log(counter);
```

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm. Don't know why I have not thought of this earlier.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var nameArray = ['AA', 'BB', 'WBB'];
var idArray = ['AA','BB','CC'];

const match = (source, target) => source.filter(value => target.includes(value)).length

console.log(match(nameArray, idArray))
```